# "following" vs "this"

Tags: word-choice

Suppose I want to ask a question and want to mention an error in my program like this:

> I keep on receiving **the following** error "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token : ".

Is the above sentence correct or I should change it to :

> I keep on receiving **this** error "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token : ".

Please note that I'm providing the error in place and not in a line below the sentence.

Comment: As Christian has said, both are correct.  However, in either case you should add a colon after "error".  (You should not do so in his examples.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences will be understood.

The more correct one is the one using **'the following error'.**

To use a pronoun like 'this' in writing you should identify what you are referring to first.

Or you could just say:

- I keep on receiving the error "Uncaught....".
- I keep on receiving an "Uncaught Syntax" error. 
  (if the error text is shorter and doesn't break up your sentence too much).